# Scraping text from a <span> within another <span> tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

EDIT: I noticed I mixed up the code from one and the output from another script. Here is the right code with the right output

```html
<div class="ingredient-list single-column">
    <div class="ingredient-list__part">
        <ul aria-labelledby="ingredients-title">
            <li>
                <span class="ingredient">
                    <span class="ingredient__product">aardappel (vastkokend)</span>
                    <span class="ingredient__unit">1 kg</span>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="ingredient">
                    <span class="ingredient__product">sjalot</span>
                    <span class="ingredient__unit">1</span></span>
            </li>
            <li> ...
```

I'm trying to extract the information within the span with ingredient__product and ingredient__unit separately.

The code I have written goes as follows:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://dagelijksekost.een.be/gerechten/makreel-met-aardappelen-in-de-schil-en-rode-biet"


#open connectie en pagina pakken
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsen
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


ingredients = page_soup.find("ul",{"aria-labelledby":"ingredients-title"})

ingredient = ingredients.findAll('li')

for i in range(len(ingredient)):
    print(ingredient[i].text.strip())
```

This was my first attempt and returns me this output:

- 1 kg aardappel
- 1 sjalot
- ...

I want to separate the information in the span tag so I tried modifying my code as follows:

```py
ingredients = page_soup.find_all("span", {"class": "ingredient"})

print(ingredients)
```

This only prints an empty list. It seems like I can't "access" the information between span tags

What am I doing wrong?

If I have solved this step the next step would be to cycle through multiple recipes on this site. Any tips regarding how to cycle through URLs where the part after gerechten/ is variable is welcome as well.

Comment: Page wasn't returning the data unless I open it with browser which seems that it renders data from JavaScript, you should use Selenium for that case.

Comment: Your ouput does not match your code at all. Show us the real output.

Comment: @KlausD. I just noticed I was running the previous version which indeed gave me this output. This code gives me an error

Comment: There is no way for your current attempt to produce the faulty output you claim to have.

Comment: @SIM I'm sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question so it has the right information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_all` to get all `<span>` tags with `class="ingredient"` then loop through the result then parse the data as in the code below:

```
ingredients = page_soup.find_all("span", {"class": "ingredient"})
for ingredient in ingredients:
    print("ingredient product: ", ingredient.find(class_='ingredient__product').text)
    print("ingredient unit: ", ingredient.find(class_='ingredient__unit').text)
    print("-")
```

**EDIT:**
Parsing data from ingredients variable within JS, although I would recommend using Selenium with a web-browser like PhantomJS for getting the data which is being pulled from javascript in the html code:

```
import json
import re

load = json.loads(re.findall(r"var ingredients = (.*?);", str(page_soup))[0])

for i in load:
    if i['unit'] != None:
        print("unit:", i["amount"], i["unit"]["name"])
    else:
        print("unit:", i["amount"])
    print("product:", i["product"]["name"], i["append"])
    print("-")
```

Output:

```
unit: 1 kg
product: aardappel (vastkokend)
-
unit: 1
product: sjalot
-
unit: 0
product: rode wijnazijn
-
unit: 4
product: rode biet (gekookt)
-
...
```

Comment: diff between find_all and findAll ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη bs3 uses findAll while bs4 use find_all, both does the same thing.

Comment: I tried running this code and this returns nothing.

Comment: @JanDries Because it's based on the html content you specified.

Answer (score 1):

The formatted items you are interested in are within some script tag. Try the following to dig the required items out of that script tag.

```
import re
import json
import requests

link = 'https://dagelijksekost.een.be/gerechten/makreel-met-aardappelen-in-de-schil-en-rode-biet'

res = requests.get(link)
json_obj = json.loads(re.findall(re.compile(r"var ingredients =(.*?);",re.DOTALL), res.text)[0])
for ingrdnt in json_obj:
    print(ingrdnt['product']['name'])
```

Output you may have are like:

```
aardappel
sjalot
rode wijnazijn
rode biet
lente-ui
augurken
```